# Alt-tab does not switch apps inside Amazon Workspace on Chromebook

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, amazon-web-services, chromebook, google-chrome-os, workspace

I'm using a Lenovo Chromebook, and one of the applications I'm using is the [Amazon WorkSpaces Chromebook Client Application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/userguide/amazon-workspaces-chromebook-client.html). My problem is that when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> it switches out of the WorkSpaces client. But I want to stay inside WorkSpaces and just have alt-tab switch apps inside the workspace.

I did find one post from somebody else with the same problem:

- [Android + External Keyboard: Alt+Tab not recognised by WorkSpaces client](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=225393)

How can I change the behaviour of Alt-Tab with the AWS WorkSpaces client?

Comment: I found a blog post about switching RDP between full-screen and windowed mode, but it's not useful to me because the Chromebook doesn't have a Break key. https://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2013/2/6/remote_desktop_keyboard_shortcuts

Comment: I also looked in `chrome://flags` but found nothing useful there

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is for Chromebook, but I realized that for my Mac client `option + tab` does the trick, while `command + tab` lets you switch in the host apps.

Answer (score 0):

On the Linux client, it currently works while in full screen mode. On windowed mode, it is possible to use `super + alt + tab` to switch applications.

Note: `super` is the *Windows* key